# How to add tags to a folder in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, tags

I know it is possible to add tags to [specific files](https://superuser.com/questions/385546/how-to-add-tags-to-files-in-windows-7-so-that-they-appear-in-search-results) in a folder, but is it possible to add tags directly to folder? 
I have a ton of folders which I would like to sort based on tags.

Comment: The functionality of tags hasn't changed.  If you couldn't do it in Windows 7 you can't do it in Windows 10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I built a simple tool for tagging folders in Windows 10. This tool is based on the well-documented system file "desktop.ini" which was designed to customize many aspects of the folder's behavior in Microsoft Windows. The system file already has the folder-tagging capability built into it. For whatever reasons, Microsoft did not implement any user-friendly interface to use the capability. This tool provides an easy way to modify the system file using GUI input dialog box. All you need to do is to register a batch file to your system registry without any need to install additional programs.

If you are interested, please follow these steps at your own risk.

#### Step 1: Download Tag_Folder.bat from the link below.

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ielPA2kVfVDe4GAjprqtuO5dcX3qJyz3/view
- Do your own due diligence by inspecting the batch file.

#### Step 2: Add “Tag Folder” to your context menu using Regedit.exe

- Open the Registry Editor:

  - Hit `Win+R`
  - type `regedit`
  - Hit `Enter`
  - Select “Yes”
- Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`
- Create a new key `Tag Folder` within `shell`
- Create a new key `command` within `Tag Folder`
- Select `command` and double-click on “(Default)” in the right panel
- Enter `cmd /c start "" /min "yourpath\Tag_Folder.bat"` in the “Value data” field
- Hit “OK”

#### Step 3: Organize your folders with custom tags.

- Go to the folder you wish to tag.
- Right-click in the blank space and click “Tag Folder”
- Enter your tag in the GUI input dialog box and Click OK.
- You may have to refresh several times to see the new tags.

You can find more information in the description of my tutorial video posted on Youtube.

[How to Tag Folders in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyFhSdm4gD8)

---

In an effort to prevent link rot, the contents of the batch file linked above are pasted here:

```
<# : Tag_Folder.bat v1.1
:: Adds a tag to current folder in Windows 10
:: by Pinjoy  2-10-2019  
:: pinjoy99@gmail.com
:: https://youtu.be/vyFhSdm4gD8
:: v1.1 updated on 5-1-2019: Refresh folder tags instantly

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') DO (
    ATTRIB -h -s desktop.ini >NUL
    TYPE desktop.ini|FINDSTR /V "F29F85E0 Prop5" > "%temp%\desktop.ini"
    ECHO [{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}] >> "%temp%\desktop.ini"
    ECHO Prop5=31,%%~I >> "%temp%\desktop.ini"
    (
     echo set shell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
     echo set folder = shell.NameSpace^("%cd%"^)
     echo folder.MoveHere "%temp%\desktop.ini", 4+16+1024
    )>"%temp%\updateTag.vbs"
    cscript //nologo //b "%temp%\updateTag.vbs"
    ATTRIB +h +s desktop.ini
)
EXIT

: end Batch portion / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-object Windows.Forms.Form
$label = New-Object Windows.Forms.Label
$textbox = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button

$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(240,150)
$form.Text = "Tag Folder"
$form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.AcceptButton = $button

$label.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20,20)
$label.Size  = New-Object Drawing.Size(180,23)
$label.Text  = "Enter your tag"

$textbox.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(20,43)
$textbox.Size  = New-Object Drawing.Size(180,23)

$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(160,76)
$button.Size  = New-Object Drawing.Size(50,23)
$button.Text  = "OK"
$button.DialogResult = "OK"
$button.Add_Click({$form.Close()})

$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($textbox)
$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.ShowDialog()
Write-Output ""$textbox.Text""
```

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST THING SINCE CHEESECAKE! YOU CAN GROUP BY TAGS AND HAVE ORGANIZED FOLDERS!
Btw, I read your script. The windows shell is really cryptic :) massive kudos!

Comment: The folders really do look beautiful with this, thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to remove tags? Also, I can’t give this answer enough up-votes.

Comment: Inspired by your piece of code: https://github.com/Jamminroot/intag

Comment: Incredible, Thank You! Just what I was looking for. Btw, if you want to change the tags *on* a folder, instead of *in* it, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Tag Folder\command` you can add  `cmd /c "start /d "%1" /min "<yourpath>\Tag_Folder.bat""` P.S., the quotes around Tag_Folder.bat are unnecessary if the path does not have any spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tool. Can you please expand the video a bit showing how tags are actually useful? E.g. using Explorer to list all directories with a given tag. Also, would this work with WSL/WSL2?

Comment: @opyate What the `bat` file does is to add `[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]\nProp5=31,YourTag` to `desktop.ini` file inside the specified directory. For linux, all you need to do is to grep tags inside those `desktop.ini` files. For example `grep -r -e "YourTag" **/*desktop.ini` will list the directories that contain specified tag.

Comment: @Ignat, can you explain the difference between `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell`? I could ask another question, but it seems relevant here.

Comment: @RandyCragun I'm not an expert, but I believe Directory\Background\ is only for commands executed when interacting with the literal background whitespace of an explorer folder directory, while Folder\ is for anything folder related at all. Folder\ is more generic.

Comment: There is a list to choose by what to sort. In this list the word "tag" does not appear on my system (WIn10). So I can tag a folder but can not see the tags. Others having the same problem?

Answer (score 3):

Without third-party tool(like [tagspaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/)), we cannot tag folder directly.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect, see the Tag Folder answer.

Comment: Yes you can, you only need Windows Explorer and Notepad, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's simple.

Let's say you want to add tags to `C:\MyFolder`. Create a new file `C:\MyFolder\desktop.ini` and set its contents to the following:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
[{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9}]
Prop5=31,Tag1; Tag2
```

Windows Explorer will now show `C:\MyFolder` with Tags set to 'Tag1 Tag2'. Explorer will treat Tag1 and Tag2 as separate when it comes to Group By->Tags for example.

Note you can set other folder properties like Title in the same way. I can't find authoritative (Microsoft) documentation but if you search the internet for `F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9` you will find useful information, for example https://superuser.com/a/1292027/207199.

Comment: Simplest solution that worked for me

Comment: Note that if you are viewing files by grouping, e.g. `View ▶ group by ▶ Tags` to check the results, The change will be reflected only after you have also changed the grouping methods and then changed this back. a simple refresh with using `F5` won't work

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the ADD TAGS option does not comes up in Explorer then use the following :

With help from another user I found a way to add TAGs easily .
You will need to open folder from your native user Folder for e.g **D:\My Documents**
instead of **Libraries>Documents>My Documents**. After that you can change TAG from the explorer>Select file>Properties> edit TAGs

Don't ask me why but it works that way. If you have made any shortcuts or favorites you will need to make them again going through the **D:\My Documents** path!

Comment: For tagging files, it's right-click and then Details. Where are these "Add tags" and "Edit tags" options? Third-party software perhaps? And the question was about tagging folders, not files.