# Tags entered with Shell script do not appear in Tags column

Tags: cmd.exe, tags

I downloaded the script into my Users Folder:

```
cmd /c "start /min C:\Users\mattrupp.AGILENT\Documents\tagfolderScript\Tag_Folder.bat"
```

I was able to Find the Right click menu "Tag Files" and after invoking it. I was able to enter a Tag value, for a short moment another File entry Called "Desktop.ini" appeared and vanished.

Unfortunately no Tag value that I entered ever appeared in my List view. Is there any way to start the bat File manually in order to see if it runs into an error during execution?

Sorry I am not an expert in PS or scripting.

Comment: What does the `.bat` file do? How did you modify the context menu? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Paste `C:\Users\mattrupp.AGILENT\Documents\tagfolderScript\Tag_Folder.bat` into an open command prompt.

Comment: MY problems refers to a thread  here: https://superuser.com/questions/1263318/how-to-add-tags-to-a-folder-in-windows-10  , I initially tried to add a comment to it , but was told that i do not have enough points to do so 

Apparently I am new to this and was unable to add my question to this article. I did  follow all the instructions in this article, but was not able to succeed