# Cant choose "tag" after Tag_Folder.bat

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, tags

I found [this](https://superuser.com/a/1408215/1785471) great answer that shows how to add tags to folders on Windows 10 but unfortunately it does not work as expected. If I right-click in a folder I can enter a tag but the problem is that I can not choose "tag" being a variable to sort or group by folders. I can choose from things like "name", "date", and so on, but "tag" not listed. Is this an error others experience, too? Is there some workaround?

Also: I noticed that in the video the added command to registry is `cmd /c "start /min yourpath\Tag_Folder.bat"` and in the answer it is `cmd /c start "" /min "yourpath\Tag_Folder.bat"`. Tried both, still not wirking.

EDIT: I found even another version `cmd /c start "" /d "%1" /min "<path>\Tag_Folder.bat"` on [github](https://github.com/hugonun/Tag-Windows-Folder/blob/main/README.md) but it does not work either. In fact after this I can not even add a tag to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are useful in searches, for example `tag:blivo` will find all documents with that tag, but to see them in Windows *Explorer*, you must add the column *Tags* to the display, as below:

[image: Display tags]

- In Window *Explorer*, right-click on the column headers.
- Click on *Tags* to add that column.
- Any item that has a **valid Windows tag** will display it, e.g., "cren" or "blivo" in the screenshot.
- Click on the *Tags* column header to sort on that, e.g., *Tags* show a down-caret to show sorting on *Tags* in descending order. Click again to revers the sort order.

**For this to work correctly, the tag must be in a format recognized by Windows and the file system. If the "tag" is embedded elsewhere, perhaps in an additional field for a document, Windows might know nothing of it.

Comment: On the screenshot there is the list I meant in my question: you can choose from "Name", "Date modified", ... and "Tag". But in my list the "Tag" is missing. My question is whether others have the same problem and how to add "Tag" to this list.

Comment: And the word "Tag" does not appear either in the long list that appears after clicking "More"

Comment: @IngoPingo, the item is "Tags", not "Tag", and is shown in the **Details** in Windows 10, v. 21H2. Perhaps you have another version?

Comment: I don't have "Tags" in the list, in neither of them.  I have another version. Any chance to add "Tags" if they are missing?

Comment: Perhaps you have an intentionally restricted version, such as Windows 10 in S mode, It is unlikely you could add another field to the existing version, but you can upgrade to a newer or better OS.